# Does any security market use real-time settlements?

Tags: trading, stock-markets, settling-and-clearing

I read on [cnbc.com](https://www.cnbc.com/2021/02/18/citadels-ken-griffin-defends-controversial-wall-street-practice-says-firm-would-adapt-if-it-were-outlawed.html) ([mirror](https://archive.vn/lVpFr)):

> Tenev also advocated for real-time settlement instead of two-day settlement in order to help combat some of the chaos that occurred during the GameStop saga.

Does any security market use  real-time settlements?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [T, T+1, T+2 trading modes](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/131048/t-t1-t2-trading-modes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no security market that use real-time settlements for stocks. However, as this [Reddit discussion](https://redd.it/10z967g) note, some other financial products such as futures and bitcoins settle immediately.